# Using Twilio/XML without Rails

Tags: ruby, xml, twilio

I am attempting to write a Twilio script to do voice broadcasting without rails - I would like to be able to run the script straight from my terminal.

I have a very simple script, straight from the `twilio-rb` gem docs:

```
# This should be in an initializer or similar
Twilio::Config.setup \
  :account_sid  => account,
  :auth_token   => token

  Twilio::Call.create :to => '+1234567890', :from => '+0987654321',
                    :url => xml_file
```

`xml_file` is a xml file on my local machine, but it throws this error:

`Error #21205: Url is not a valid url`

How can I write the above script to operate off of a local xml file? The end goal is strictly to make a phone call, play an audio message, gather a button press and do an action based on the number received. The Twiml XML file should do that for me, if I can get it to work.

EDIT:

When using the dropbox share link, I get this error within the Twilio interface:

```
'Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL. Please see the Twilio Markup XML Documentation for more information on valid Content-Types.

You must return a Content-Type for all requests. Requests without a Content-Type will appear in the Debugger as a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Having a phone number, outgoing call request or action attribute refer to a non XML or audio resource.
Having a Play verb attempt to play non-audio content, such as XML or text.
Verify that that your web server is returning a Content-Type and it is the expected value
Make sure the URL noted refers to a valid resource'
```

To make sure, I copied an example I know will work into my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say voice="man">Hey man! Listen to this!</Say>
  <Play>http://foo.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
  <Say voice="man">What did you think of that?!</Say>
  <Record action="http://foo.com/handleRecording.php" method="GET" maxLength="20" finishOnKey="*"/>
  <Gather action="/process_gather.php" method="GET">
    <Say>Now hit some buttons!</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Say voice="man">Awesome! Thanks!</Say>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two ideas to try:**

**(1)** If the file is read locally and sent to the Twilio server, try:

```
:url => 'file:///path/file.xml'
```

**where**

- `host` in `//host/` is omitted, yielding three slashes in a row.
- `path` is the full filesystem path to your XML file.
- `file.xml` is the name of your XML file.

**(2)** If the file must be publicly readable by the Twilio server, try placing it in the cloud somewhere (such as Dropbox) and using the public URL to it there.

Comment: Hmm no dice. The format makes sense though. This is what I end up with:

 `:url => 'file:///Users/Luigi/Desktop/work/Dropbox/Twilio/xml.xml'`

But I still get the same error.

Comment: If the URL must be publicly accessible, perhaps the URL given by Dropbox->Share Link would be worth a try.

Comment: Good thinking, I think that's a step forward - It actually makes the call as intended, but the XML isn't read - just throws an application error recording instead of playing as it should. I know the xml is valid as I have used the same xml through twilio's "twimlets" functionality and it works fine.

Comment: Looking into it further it seems that it's throwing a 403 error, access forbidden. Twilio doesn't have access to view my dropbox file...

Comment: Problem may now be reduced to one of tweaking Dropbox access control for the file.  Use the Dropbox public folder?  If you can get the file to come up in an unauthenticated browser (use incognito mode), then Twilio should also have access.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. It's accepting the URL so I should be able to troubleshoot from here. Thanks for the help!